# Getting a specific element in ngFor using Viewchildren

Tags: angular, viewchildren

My question is that can I use viewchildren to access a specific element with some dynamic id inside *ngFor? using viewchildren it returns an array of all the elements with that reference variable. If I give some id to every element which is dynamically updated, can I access the element using this id ?

Example HTML :

```
   <div #divs *ngFor="let item of [1,2]" [id]="'div-' + item">
    Div  {{item}}
   </div>
  
   <button (click)="getDivs()">Get divs</button>`
```

Example TS :

```
  @ViewChildren("divs") divs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

I know we can loop through the querylist but I want to know if we can access by some identifier like id.

If I want to access id = "div-2" and change its color to red, or do something else, how can I do that?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add a property to each item and use the property in the template. If you change the property value, Angular will update the rendered view.

Comment: In general, you only use ViewChild/ViewChildren when you need to access the native dom element. If you are tweaking styles, you could use ngClass, or if you are doing something interactive, use a click handler which passes info about the element to the handler function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle a different style for an individual `div` by using `ViewChildren`, you could do it by listening to a click event on each `div` and then find that div clicked with its `id` from the array like the following:

**component.ts**

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
  ids = [1, 2]
  selected!: string | undefined;
  @ViewChildren('divs') divs!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  setColor(): void {   
    if (selected) {
     const found = this.divs.find(e => e.nativeElement.id === this.selected)
     console.log('element found: ', found)

     // apply a style to it
     if (found) {
       found.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
     }
    }    
  }
}
```

**template**

```html
<div 
 #divs 
 *ngFor="let item of ids" 
 [id]="'div-' + item" 
 (click)="selected = 'div-' + item"> // click on a div will set its id to "selected"
     <h1>Div  {{item}}</h1>
</div>
  
<button (click)="setColor()">Get divs</button>
```

Or handle the styles with a `css` class within the template HTML like so:

**template**

```html
<div 
 #divs 
 *ngFor="let item of ids" 
 [id]="'div-' + item" 
 [class.colorBlue]="{ selected === 'div-' + item }"
 (click)="selected = 'div-' + item">
     <h1>Div  {{item}}</h1>
</div>
```

**css**

```css
.colorBlue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2gkiar?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)